# Как создать CSRF сессию из remember_token в laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

хочу привязать сайт к приложению laravel. Как я могу сгенерировать куки, такие же как у Laravel, используя remember_token? (желательно без использования самого laravel, ибо не углублялся) Или это не так работает?

Comment: Что значит привязать сайт к приложению?

Comment: Есть готовое приложение на Laravel, хочу объединить сессию со своим сайтом на php